# Firing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My current project is to make space invaders in python. I am using the pygame library to help me do so. So far everything works fine except the player firing. When the player presses left control the player should fire one bullet, instead the player will keep firing until told to do something else like move. If anyone could help me with this problem it would be much appreciated, the code is below, thanks.

```
    def update(self):
    self.speed_x = 0
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.speed_x = -10
    if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.speed_x = 10
    self.rect.x += self.speed_x
    if self.rect.right > DISPLAY_WIDTH:
        self.rect.right = DISPLAY_WIDTH
    if self.rect.left < 0:
        self.rect.left = 0
    if keystate[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
        player.shoot()
```

Comment: You should post definition of `shoot`.

Comment: it is because you use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` which gives `True` all the time - till you release `K_LCTRL`. You can use `fired = True/False` to controll if you fired first bullet. Or use `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()` because `event` is created only once - when button change state from not-pressed to pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem because you use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` which gives `True` all the time - till you release `K_LCTRL`.

You can use `fired = True/False` to controll if you fired first bullet.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.fired = False

def update(self):
    if keystate[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
        if not self.fired:
            player.shoot()
            self.fired = True
    else:
        self.fired = False
```

---

Or use `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()` because `event` is created only once - when button change state from `not-pressed` to `pressed`. (the same `KEYUP` is created only once - when button change state from `pressed` to `not-pressed`)

```
def handle_event(self, event):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if pygame.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
            player.shoot()
```

and execute it in mainloop

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    your_object.handle_event(event)
```